# Ember nested routes and promises

Tags: javascript, ember.js

When accessing an ember URL directly with nested routes, the app does not wait for parent promises to resolve before loading nested resources.

Here's an example code:

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('index', {path: "/"}, function () {
        this.resource('project', {path: "/project/:id"}, function () {
            this.resource('file', {path: "/file/:encodedPath"});
        });
    });
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return Ember.$.getJSON('/list-projects');
    }
});

App.ProjectRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function (controller, model) {
        return Ember.$.getJSON('/load-project?id=' + model.id).then(
                function (data) {
                    controller.set('model', data);
                });
    }
});

App.FileRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function (controller, model) {
        var project = this.modelFor('project');
        var url = '/load-file?project=' + project.id + '&path=' + model.encodedPath;

        return Ember.$.getJSON(url).then(
            function (data) {
                controller.set('model', data);
            });

    }
});
```

Is it possible to wait for the project data to resolve before loading file data?

The problem only occurs when loading the URL directly in the browser: 
http://mywebsite.com/#/project/1234/file/test.txt

Thanks.

Comment: This is a bit of a guess, but you could try doing `this.controllerFor('project').get('model').then(function(projectModel){ ... })` inside your `FileRoute`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Jamie but that didn't work. "Error while processing route: file Cannot read property 'then' of null TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of null"

Comment: I think instead of using `setupController` you should just be using the `model` hook like you've done for your `IndexRoute`. The model hook is passed  `params` which you can use to get the passed in `projectId`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comments to your question, this should do the trick. Note the `model` hook can return a `Promise` whereas `setupController` shouldn't return anything.

Here is a JSBin that tries correspond with your project - obviously the data is different:
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/letalehoje/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Make sure you view it externally as well: 
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/letalehoje/1/#/project/1/file/text1-1.txt

```
App.ProjectRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return Ember.$.getJSON('/load-project?id=' + params.id);
    }
});

App.FileRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        var projectPromise = this.modelFor('project');

        return Ember.RSVP.resolve(projectPromise).then(function(project) {
            // this is the promise that should be returned for the FileRoute model
            return Ember.$.getJSON('/load-file?project=' + project.id + '&path=' + params.encodedPath);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: When I replace the setupControler function with a model function, links stop working. Am I missing something? Also this.controllerFor('project').get('model'); is not returning a promise. Thanks.

Comment: @Elie my bad. Use this instead `var projectPromise = this.modelFor('project');` I've edited my answer and included a JSBin to try to show that it works.

Comment: You know what, now that I have this in JSBin - everything should just work if you have your `{{outlets}}` set up correct. Ember should just wait for the project to resolve before loading the `FileRoute`. Here's another JSBin that is simplified: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/bofegedifu/1/edit?html,js  and http://emberjs.jsbin.com/bofegedifu/1#/project/2/file/text2-1.txt

Comment: Thanks Jamie. I actually realized that the "model" function will never be called if you're using {{link-to 'project' project}}. Ember will assume that the model is project and will not try to reload it via API. I haven't figured out how to force Ember to load the model from the API when using {{link-to}} but that's a different problem.

Comment: Instead of passing project pass project.id and Ember should call the model hook regardless.